# Нету переводов строк по новому функционалу подписок на сообщения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, подписки

[The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/260198).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пока добавил хоть какие-то переводы, чтобы английский текст глаза не мозолил. Больший вопрос вызывает именно перевод слова **follow**.

Его обсуждаем [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10266/15479).