# Follow - "подписаться" или "отслеживать"?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, подписки

Выкатили [новый функционал подписок на сообщения](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/260198). Много [не переведённых строк](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10265/15479).

Часто используется слово **follow**. Будем использовать перевод "следовать/отслеживать" или "подписаться"?

Если у вас есть другой вариант, опубликуйте ответом.

Comment: Почему бы не навесить [важное]?

Comment: А зачем так длинно, может «следить»?

Comment: @andreymal примерно то же самое)

Comment: Преследовать :)

Comment: @insolor (ﾒ￣▽￣)︻┳═一

Comment: Удивлюсь, если кто-то, кто узнал о фиче из этого сообщения, не нажал на новую ссылочку :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ у парней [явные проблемы с UX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345667/260198).

Comment: Эти [двойные тул-типы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW2vm.png) конечно...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ через несколько лет может и допилят дизайн свой :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Отслеживать.

---

Comment: Отслеживать просто более "по-стаковерфловски" — ведь метки у нас отслеживают.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica ну лично я бы предпочёл и за метками следить тоже)

Answer (score 6):

Подписаться.

---

Answer (score 1):

Следить.

---